# IE8 expanding panel overflows its container, except

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I thought I'd post this question without adding any code and a huge amount of detail as the solution  may (hopefully) be something obvious.

I'm using jQuery to expand panels and when I expand a panel with a reasonable amount of content, the panel overflows the container making the page a little messy looking.  However, if I then resize the browser window slightly horizontally, the container mysteriously fixes itself and covers the content as it should.

The issue only occurs in IE8. I'm using IE Tester and have not tested in IE8 proper. I'm using ASP.NET with Ajax.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you can fix it by setting **zoom:1;** in css on the container.

Comment: Thanks - tried this but didn't do it.  Also applied it to all divs just in case  but that no good either.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try triggering any CSS change on a page element in the callback function for your slideToggle. I recently encountered a similar problem and just by toggling a class (with no CSS properties for that class, just a name) it triggered a layout change in IE8 for some unknown reason. This was the only way I could get IE8 to respond to my content size change.